# (Android) How to display a textbox outside a listview's cells, but still have it as part of the viewholder

Tags: android, xml, listview, overlay

[image]

As shown above, I'd like to display the popup textbox (with the "Done" button) outside of the first cell, overlaying the rest of the views.

What I've done so far:

- Had the viewholder layout as a coordinator layout
- in the viewholder layout, i added the following xml:
  android:clipChildren="false"
  android:clipToPadding="false"
- I made my textbox popup layout, and added a negative margin to it so it would appear outside the parent layout
- this, however, makes the textbox popup hidden from view because other cells are on top.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? What's an easier way to display a textbox popup like the one above for each cell in a listview/recyclerview?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to display text using ToolTip

```
Listview lv=(Listview)tooltip.findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
long id) {
    new SimpleTooltip.Builder(this)
    .anchorView(view)
    .text("Something")
    .gravity(Gravity.END)
    .animated(true)
    .transparentOverlay(false)
    .build()
    .show();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I can't find SimpleToolTip class, but I did find a close alternative, so I'm experimenting with that. I think this will be the easiest solution. Thanks again!